# Changing default shiny grayed app screen on app quit

Tags: r, shiny

When a shiny app quits, in the browser, everything becomes grayed out.

What if, instead of the grayed out app, I want to show a white html page that says : App closed.

I think I should be able to use the `shiny::onStop` function, but how to get this function to display an HTML/CSS message across the page instead of grayed out shiny app?